# What does this quote in Small Gods refer to?

Tags: quotes, discworld, terry-pratchett, small-gods

In *Small Gods*, by Terry Pratchett, the following quote appears:

> It was something he shared with tortoises. Watch any tortoise walking,
>   and periodically it will stop while it files away the memories of the
>   journey so far. Not for nothing, elsewhere in the multiverse, are the
>   little traveling devices controlled by electric thinking-engines
>   called “turtles.”

What are the "little travelling devices" referring to?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's a reference to the use of [Logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language)) (a programming language) to control robots referred to as "[turtles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_(robot))".

[image]

Comment: Further to that (as someone who spent more time than I care to remember on my school's Beebs!)... It's worth mentioning that since the BBC was not a particularly fast machine, Logo was an interpreted language, and the comms link to the Turtle was pretty slow, you would always have a short delay when the Turtle completed one move and the system got itself set up for the next move.

Comment: [This photo of Sir Terrence at work](https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3265/2329991390_70b23155d3_z.jpg?zz=1) may help explain how all these computer references got into his fantasy world(s).

Comment: @Pavel - But no turtle....

Comment: @Valorum: but I bet he had a mouse.

Comment: @BobJarvis - He seems to have had several, an Ativa ergonomic mouse; https://d3idt3y1vhsqn9.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/15002651/terry-11.jpg and a white Intel Mouse that he donated to the Terry Pratchett Museum; https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DPf8SpyX0AAUdj-.jpg

Comment: I had always supposed it was a reference to [turtle graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics), but this seems to fit better.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - The software "turtle" predated the physical turtle robot by only about a year. When someone refers to a logo turtle, they're not usually referring to the software that runs it, but the wheeled robot.

Comment: When it's necessary to distinguish, the preferred terms (or at least the ones used by Seymour Papert) are "screen turtle" and "floor turtle".

Comment: It's turtles, all the way down...